# Right-click on home folder in unity launcher does not populate the bookmark list

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, shortcuts

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I also installed Unity Window Quicklists by following [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/unity-window-quicklists-switch-between.html) link.
I added a few bookmarks (shortcuts) to the left side selection in nautilus:
http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.sk/2012/05/ubuntu-1204-adding-bookmarksshortcuts.html

and this way, when I right-click the home folder in unity launcher  it populates those shortcuts.

BUT, as soon as I use a shortcut that way (so I access a folder that way) and then I right-click the home folder in the unity launcher (even after I close the previously opened window)  the shortcuts do not appear anymore. Only if I log out and log back in.

Could you, please, help me to solve this issue? Thank you in advance for all the efforts and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved my issue by uninstalling Unity Window Quicklists, since I did not use it as much as the shortcuts.